# Story about brute soldiers psychically linked to operators

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to find a story I read a while ago, but I can't remember all of the details. This was probably a short story, either in a collection or a sci-fi magazine. I usually read Analog, Asimov's, and Fantasy and Science Fiction, but I didn't find it in the issues I still have.

Basically there are these enhanced Brute soldiers (I think that's actually what they are called, but I can't remember for sure) that are operated remotely by other soldiers. These are biological brutes, this is NOT *Forever Peace* by Joe Haldeman. One of the only other details that I can remember is that one of the brute soldiers is thought to be killed in action, but later turns up (I think fighting in a cage match?), and it is discovered that they have more of a mind than the operators were lead to believe. I'm 99% sure this is set on Earth.

Comment: Can you remember what media this was? Book, film, etc.? Are there any other specific plot points you can remember? If so could you [edit] in some extra information?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Just to eliminate a few possibilities: From Steve's summary, I feel certain that his story is **not** "Call Me Joe" by Poul Anderson, **nor** "The Body Builders" by Keith Laumer. Both stories start with the premise of an intelligent man making his living by remote-controlling a big strong body to do dangerous things (gladiatorial combat in Laumer's case; exploring and colonizing the surface of Jupiter in Anderson's case), but the plots go in very different directions from what Steve describes.